# How to export Allure report to artifacts in gitlab ci job?

Tags: gitlab-ci, allure

I'm trying to configure job for gitlab CI which should run restassured tests and generate an allure report. I want to export report to artifacts but don't know how.
Here is job config

```
automation_tests:   
stage: autotests   
script:
        - chmod +x gradlew
        - echo "Starting automation testing"
        - ./gradlew -g /cache/.gradle test --tests "RestAssuredTests"
        - echo "Automation tests were executed"
        - ./gradlew clean build allureReport ((???))  
artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
          - report
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example `.gitlab-ci.yml` that exports a (mock) report:

```
myjob:
  script:
    - mkdir reports/
    - date >> reports/date.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - reports/
```

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactspaths

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Check where report stores after task and specify this path to artifacts

```
> Task :allureReport
 Report successfully generated to path/build/reports/allure-report

automation_tests:
  stage: autotests
  script:
    - chmod +x gradlew
    - echo "Starting automation testing"
    - ./gradlew test --tests testClass
    - echo "Automation tests were executed"
    - ./gradlew clean build allureReport
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - build/reports/allure-report/
    expire_in: 1 hour
```